# I am upgrading spring boot from 1.4.4 release to 2.7.12 releases ... and i am facing below exception

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as well as SecurityFilterChain. Please select just one.

As per the spring guidance, i have removed usage of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and added the SecurityFilterChain. I made sure my code does not extends any WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
However, i am still getting the exception. I tried to search from where WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is getting linked and i found out that spring-security-oauth2 has spring-security-config and under that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is getting linked.

How to solved this, please help.

Comment: `spring-security-oauth2` is end of life since 2022. You have to remove it. OAuth2 suppport is now part of Spring Security 5/6.